# How to print Unicode character in C++

Tags: c++, unicode, iostream, cout, wchar-t

I am trying to print a Russian "ф" ([U+0444](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0400.pdf) CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER EF) character, which is given a code of decimal [1092](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4). Using C++, how can I print out this character? I would have thought something along the lines of the following would work, yet...

```
int main (){
   wchar_t f = '1060';
   cout << f << endl;
}
```

Comment: Note that the problem is two-fold (at least when it comes to a valid C++ program): expressing the character in code, and correctly passing it to `std::cout`. (And even when those two steps are done correctly it's a different matter altogether of correctly displaying the character inside whatever `std::cout` is connected to.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unicode encoding for string literals in C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796157/unicode-encoding-for-string-literals-in-c11)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

To represent the character you can use Universal Character Names (UCNs). The character 'ф' has the Unicode value U+0444 and so in C++ you could write it '\u0444' or '\U00000444'. Also if the source code encoding supports this character then you can just write it literally in your source code.

```
// both of these assume that the character can be represented with
// a single char in the execution encoding
char b = '\u0444';
char a = 'ф'; // this line additionally assumes that the source character encoding supports this character
```

Printing such characters out depends on what you're printing to. If you're printing to a Unix terminal emulator, the terminal emulator is using an encoding that supports this character, and that encoding matches the compiler's execution encoding, then you can do the following:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, ф or \u0444!\n";
}
```

This program *does not* require that 'ф' can be represented in a single char. On OS X and most any modern Linux install this will work just fine, because the source, execution, and console encodings will all be UTF-8 (which supports all Unicode characters).

Things are harder with Windows and there are different possibilities with different tradeoffs.

Probably the best, if you don't need portable code (you'll be using wchar_t, which should really be avoided on every other platform), is to set the mode of the output file handle to take only UTF-16 data.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main() {
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    std::wcout << L"Hello, \u0444!\n";
}
```

Portable code is more difficult.

Comment: ? I'm pretty sure '\u0444' won't fit into a char unless the compiler has promoted the char to an int, but if you want that behavior, you should use an int.

Comment: @EdwardFalk \u0444 will fit in an 8 bit `char` if the execution charset is, for example, ISO-8859-5. Specifically it will be the byte 0xE4. Note that I'm not suggesting that using such an execution charset is a good practice, I'm simply describing how C++ works.

Comment: Ahhh, you're saying the compiler will recognize \u0444 as a unicode character, and convert it to the prevailing character set, and the result will fit in a byte? I didn't know it would do that.

Comment: Yes. This is why using `\u` is different from using `\x`.

Comment: doesn't work on my lubuntu 16 laptop with terminator terminal and g++ 5.4.0,  using a std::string worked though

Answer (score 18):

When compiling with `-std=c++11`, one can simply

```
  const char *s  = u8"\u0444";
  cout << s << endl;
```

Comment: Let me recommend [Boost.Nowide](http://cppcms.com/files/nowide/html/) for printing UTF-8 strings to terminal in a portable way, so the above code will be almost unchanged.

Comment: @ybungalobill, your comment deserves an answer on its own. Would you mind creating one?

Comment: Just for my note: `\uXXXX` and `\UXXXXXXXX` are called *universal-character-name*. A string literal of the form `u8"..."` is *UTF-8 string literal*. Both are specified in the standard.

Answer (score 12):

Ultimately, this is completely platform-dependent. Unicode-support is, unfortunately, very poor in Standard C++. For GCC, you will have to make it a narrow string, as they use UTF-8, and Windows wants a wide string, and you must output to `wcout`.

```
// GCC
std::cout << "ф";
// Windoze
wcout << L"ф";
```

Comment: They should have Unicode escapes. I'm not familiar with the notation, though.

Comment: IIRC, Unicode escapes are `\uXXXX` where the `XXXX` is for **hex** digits. Unfortunately, this leaves all the characters past U+FFFF out.

Comment: Looking at http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/0400-04FF, how should assignment play out `wchar_t x = '\u0400';` for instance, does not work

Comment: @Mike: If you want past FFFF, you can do so by generating a UTF-16 surrogate pair yourself using two instances of `\u`, at least on windows.

Comment: The OP wants to specify the character in decimal, not hex, so string escapes are kind of useless.

Comment: I'll take hex. Really, i am just looking for a way to print any character in unicode and have it displayed as it should. Using cyrillic just as an example here

Comment: @BillyONeal You do not use surrogate code points in C++ (in fact surrogate code points are completely prohibited). You use the format `\UXXXXXXXX`.

Comment: GCC is not bound to use UTF-8, and is available for Windows. `std::wcout` is also an option outside of Windows.

Comment: @Jam `'\u0400'` is a **narrow-character literal**. You seem to assume that `\u0400` exists in the execution character set. According to N3242 [lex.ccon]/5: "A universal-character-name is translated to the encoding, in the appropriate execution character set, of the
character named. If there is no such encoding, the universal-character-name is translated to an implementation defined
encoding."

Answer (score 10):

This code works in Linux ([C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11), [Geany](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geany), and [GCC 7.4](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-7/) (`g++`. 2018-12-06)):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int utf8_to_unicode(string utf8_code);
string unicode_to_utf8(int unicode);


int main()
{
    cout << unicode_to_utf8(36) << '\t';
    cout << unicode_to_utf8(162) << '\t';
    cout << unicode_to_utf8(8364) << '\t';
    cout << unicode_to_utf8(128578) << endl;

    cout << unicode_to_utf8(0x24) << '\t';
    cout << unicode_to_utf8(0xa2) << '\t';
    cout << unicode_to_utf8(0x20ac) << '\t';
    cout << unicode_to_utf8(0x1f642) << endl;

    cout << utf8_to_unicode("$") << '\t';
    cout << utf8_to_unicode("¢") << '\t';
    cout << utf8_to_unicode("€") << '\t';
    cout << utf8_to_unicode("") << endl;

    cout << utf8_to_unicode("\x24") << '\t';
    cout << utf8_to_unicode("\xc2\xa2") << '\t';
    cout << utf8_to_unicode("\xe2\x82\xac") << '\t';
    cout << utf8_to_unicode("\xf0\x9f\x99\x82") << endl;

    return 0;
}


int utf8_to_unicode(string utf8_code)
{
    unsigned utf8_size = utf8_code.length();
    int unicode = 0;

    for (unsigned p=0; p<utf8_size; ++p)
    {
        int bit_count = (p? 6: 8 - utf8_size - (utf8_size == 1? 0: 1)),
            shift = (p < utf8_size - 1? (6*(utf8_size - p - 1)): 0);

        for (int k=0; k<bit_count; ++k)
            unicode += ((utf8_code[p] & (1 << k)) << shift);
    }

    return unicode;
}


string unicode_to_utf8(int unicode)
{
    string s;

    if (unicode>=0 and unicode <= 0x7f)  // 7F(16) = 127(10)
    {
        s = static_cast<char>(unicode);

        return s;
    }
    else if (unicode <= 0x7ff)  // 7FF(16) = 2047(10)
    {
        unsigned char c1 = 192, c2 = 128;

        for (int k=0; k<11; ++k)
        {
            if (k < 6)
                c2 |= (unicode % 64) & (1 << k);
            else
                c1 |= (unicode >> 6) & (1 << (k - 6));
        }

        s = c1;
        s += c2;

        return s;
    }
    else if (unicode <= 0xffff)  // FFFF(16) = 65535(10)
    {
        unsigned char c1 = 224, c2 = 128, c3 = 128;

        for (int k=0; k<16; ++k)
        {
            if (k < 6)
                c3 |= (unicode % 64) & (1 << k);
            else if
                (k < 12) c2 |= (unicode >> 6) & (1 << (k - 6));
            else
                c1 |= (unicode >> 12) & (1 << (k - 12));
        }

        s = c1;
        s += c2;
        s += c3;

        return s;
    }
    else if (unicode <= 0x1fffff)  // 1FFFFF(16) = 2097151(10)
    {
        unsigned char c1 = 240, c2 = 128, c3 = 128, c4 = 128;

        for (int k=0; k<21; ++k)
        {
            if (k < 6)
                c4 |= (unicode % 64) & (1 << k);
            else if (k < 12)
                c3 |= (unicode >> 6) & (1 << (k - 6));
            else if (k < 18)
                c2 |= (unicode >> 12) & (1 << (k - 12));
            else
                c1 |= (unicode >> 18) & (1 << (k - 18));
        }

        s = c1;
        s += c2;
        s += c3;
        s += c4;

        return s;
    }
    else if (unicode <= 0x3ffffff)  // 3FFFFFF(16) = 67108863(10)
    {
        ;  // Actually, there are no 5-bytes unicodes
    }
    else if (unicode <= 0x7fffffff)  // 7FFFFFFF(16) = 2147483647(10)
    {
        ;  // Actually, there are no 6-bytes unicodes
    }
    else
        ;  // Incorrect unicode (< 0 or > 2147483647)

    return "";
}
```

More:

- https://sites.google.com/view/technik-informatyk-nysa/porady/porady-c-cpp#h.p_lz0skneGFILy
- [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) (Wikipedia)

Answer (score 7):

If you use Windows (note, we are using *printf()*, not *cout*):

```
// Save as UTF-8 without a signature
#include <stdio.h>
#include<windows.h>

int main (){
    SetConsoleOutputCP(65001);
    printf("ф\n");
}
```

It is not Unicode, but it is working—[Windows-1251](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251) instead of UTF-8:

```
// Save as Windows 1251
#include <iostream>
#include<windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main (){
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    cout << "ф" << endl;
}
```

Comment: SetConsoleOutputCP() has a much better name in this case.

Comment: Just FYI: default cyrillic console encoding in Windows is OEM 866.

Comment: I had to use - SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8); and printf(u8"Привет мир\n");

Answer (score 3):

In C++23 you'll be able to do it with [`std::print`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/print) which supports Unicode:

```cpp
#include <print>

int main () {
  std::print("{}\n", "ф");
}
```

Until `std::print` is widely available you can use the open-source {fmt} library, it is based on ([godbolt](https://www.godbolt.org/z/rfYPjPc1r)):

```cpp
#include <fmt/core.h>

int main () {
  fmt::print("{}\n", "ф");
}
```

Just make sure that your literal encoding is UTF-8 which is normally the default on most platforms and on Windows/MSVC is enabled with `/utf-8`.

I wouldn't recommend using `wchar_t` because it requires nonportable APIs such as `_setmode`.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the author of {fmt} and C++23 `std::print`.

Answer (score 2):

`'1060'` is four characters, and won't compile under the standard. You should just treat the character as a number, if your wide characters match 1:1 with Unicode (check your locale settings).

```
int main (){
    wchar_t f = 1060;
    wcout << f << endl;
}
```

Comment: I thought that was one of the points of iostreams: it would detect the type via overloaded `operator <<` and Do The Right Thing. Not so much, I guess?

Comment: @Jam much of this is system dependent. What OS are you using?

Comment: `'1060'` is a multi-char character literal of type `int`, and is entirely legal under standard C++. It's value is implementation defined though. Most implementations will take the values of the characters and concatenate them to produce a single integral value. These are sometimes used for so-called 'FourCC's.

Comment: I'm familiar with FourCC's (the original Mac OS used them everywhere), but every non-Mac compiler I've used emitted at least a warning when it hit a multibyte character constant. I doubt "entirely" legal would get a warning.

Comment: Perhaps you'd be surprised how many warnings there are for entirely legal code. The C++ standard says "An ordinary character literal that contains more than one c-char is a multicharacter literal. A multicharacter literal has type int and implementation-defined value." [lex.ccon] 2.14.3/1

Comment: @MikeDeSimone "_every non-Mac compiler I've used emitted at least a warning_" because it is 1) almost never used on purpose on non-Mac systems 2) not a portable construct

Comment: Both GCC and MSVC do the same concatenation of bytes, so it's at least that portable. Actually, I'm not aware of any compiler that _doesn't_ do it.

Comment: @curiousguy That was my point. And if a compiler is going to bother emitting a warning, I assume it's there for a reason and I'll avoid it. Note that bit fields are just as implementation-defined, yet generate no warnings.

Comment: @MikeDeSimonek "_Note that bit fields are just as implementation-defined_" No, they are not.

Comment: @bames53 "_Both GCC and MSVC do the same concatenation of bytes, so it's at least that portable._" OK, so I retract my non-portable statement. (But it isn't guaranteed by the standard.) Anyway, I love multi-character literals!

Comment: @curiousguy Last I checked, two things about bit fields were implementation-defined: 1) whether consecutive bit fields were packed from high-order bits to low, or low-to-high, and 2) if the total number of bits was less than the storage type, which end (MSBs or LSBs) would get the padding bits. Also see http://www.linuxforu.com/2012/01/joy-of-programming-understanding-bit-fields-c/ and http://yarchive.net/comp/linux/bitfields.html So if the standard bothered to nail down these two issues, please quote it.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone: It doesn't nail those down.  But you can use bitfields entirely portably with standard defined behaviour (and *probably* less memory consumption than if you used just a bunch of ints).  That is not true of multicharacter literals.  (Note: If you are using bitfields to try to match some externally defined storage format, the standard will not help you - so "don't do that then".)

Answer (score 1):

I needed to show the string in the UI as well as save that to an XML configuration file. The above specified format is good for string in c++, I would add we can have the xml compatible string for the special character by replacing "\u" by "&#x" and adding a ";" at the end.

For example:

C++: "\u0444" → XML : `"&#x0444;"`

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, I can just do:

```
std::cout << "ф";
```

I just copy-pasted characters from [here](https://unicode-table.com/en/) and it didn't fail for at least the random sample that I tried on.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution in Linux:

```
string a = "Ф";
cout << "Ф = \xd0\xa4 = " << hex
     << int(static_cast<unsigned char>(a[0]))
     << int(static_cast<unsigned char>(a[1])) << " (" << a.length() << "B)" << endl;

string b = "√";
cout << "√ = \xe2\x88\x9a = " << hex
     << int(static_cast<unsigned char>(b[0]))
     << int(static_cast<unsigned char>(b[1]))
     << int(static_cast<unsigned char>(b[2])) << " (" << b.length() << "B)" << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Special thanks to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1799310/1599699) for more-or-less the same question.

For me, all I needed was **`setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");`**

Then, I could use even raw `wchar_t` characters.