# C++ Unicode characters printing

Tags: c++, unicode, cout

I need to print some Unicode characters on the Linux terminal using `iostream`. Strange things happen though. When I write:

```
cout << "\u2780";
```

I get: `➀`, which is almost exactly what I want. However, if I write:

```
cout << '\u2780';
```

I get: `14851712`.

The problem is, I don't know the exact character to be printed at compile time. Therefore I'd like to do something like:

```
int x;
// Some calculations...
cout << (char)('\u2780' + x);
```

Which prints: `�`. Using `wcout` or `wchar_t` instead don't work either. How do I get correct printing?

From what I found around on the Internet, it seems important that I use the GCC 4.7.2 compiler (executable `g++`) straight from the [Debian 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_version_history#Debian_7_(Wheezy)) (Wheezy) repository.

Comment: are using wchar_t with operator `L` ? post your full code if possible or an [sscce.org](SSCCE)

Comment: If you do not want to mess with Unicode encodings, you could use a table to map strings to possible values of `x` instead of adding it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print Unicode character in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015571/how-to-print-unicode-character-in-c)

Answer (score 8):

The Unicode character `\u2780` is outside of the range for the `char` datatype. You should have received this compiler warning to tell you about it: (at least my g++ 4.7.3 gives it)

```
test.cpp:6:13: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
```

If you want to work with characters like U+2780 as single units you'll have to use the widechar datatype `wchar_t`, or if you are lucky enough to be able to work with C++11, `char32_t` or `char16_t`. Note that one 16-bit unit is not enough to represent the full range of Unicode characters.

If that's not working for you, it's probably because the default "C" locale doesn't have support for non-ASCII output. To fix that problem you can call `setlocale` in the start of the program; that way you can output the full range of characters supported by the user's locale: (which may or may not have support for all of the characters you use)

```
#include <clocale>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    wcout << L'\u2780';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which of course might have the same problem other characters (SMP) if `sizeof(wchar_t) < 4`. I'd suggest using `char16_t` or `char32_t` btw.

Comment: additionally to the encoding prefix `L`, there's `u8` for `UTF8` encoding, `u` for `char16_t`, and `U` for `char32_t`.

Comment: `setlocale` when passing a `""` for the locale name sets the user's preferred locale, that is not necessarily a Unicode locale.

Comment: Thanks @DyP, I've added the note on the new character datatypes.

Comment: Though when using g++ on Linux, `wchar_t` is in fact a 32-bit Unicode code point.  Nice to know if you care more about getting it working on Linux than being portable.

Comment: @Sventimir IIRC they left out Unicode support for streams in C++11; there's no support for `wcout << ` with a `char16_t` and `char32_t`. You'll have to either do a custom conversion from those to the expected encoding of `wchar_t` or use unformatted output.

Comment: Thank you all. Unfrotunately nothing worked for me. `char16_t` and `char32_t` print decimal representation of the character on both `cout ` and `wcout`. Setting the `CL_ALL` locale does not work either.

It seems I'll have to think of mapping int values to strings as DyP suggested instead.

Comment: @Sventimir, what's your locale (check with the `locale` command)? For me, with locale en_US.UTF-8, the test program above outputs the expected "➀"

Comment: Mine is pl_PL.UTF-8. That should not matter as long as it is UTF-8 I suppose?

Comment: If it's correctly installed and UTF-8 it shouldn't matter. If you can see Unicode output from other programs, such as `ls`, it should work.

Comment: It seems I do see proper output (such as national characters) from other programs (such as `ls`), but not from mine. Neither in the Konsole nor in Eclipse.

Comment: you might need  `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);` if you want to use both `cout` and `wcout` in this case.

Answer (score 4):

When you write

```
cout << "\u2780";
```

The compiler converts \u2780 into the appropriate encoding of that character in the execution character set. That's probably [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), and so the string ends up having four bytes (three for the character, one for the null terminator).

If you want to generate the character at run time then you need some way to do the same conversion to UTF-8 at run time that the compiler is doing at compile time.

---

C++11 provides a handy `wstring_convert` template and codecvt facets that can do this, however libstdc++, the standard library implementation that comes with GCC, has not yet gotten around to implementing them (as of [GCC 4.8.0](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/) (2013-03-22)). The following shows how to use these features, but you'll need to either use a different standard library implementation or wait for libstdc++ to implement them.

```
#include <codecvt>

int main() {
  char32_t base = U'\u2780';

  std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<char32_t>, char32_t> convert;
  std::cout << convert.to_bytes(base + 5) << '\n';
}
```

You can also use any other method of producing UTF-8 you have available. For example, [iconv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv), [ICU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Components_for_Unicode), and manual use of pre-C++11 codecvt_byname facets would all work. (I don't show examples of these, because that code would be more involved than the simple code permitted by `wstring_convert`.)

---

An alternative that would work for a small number of characters would be to create an array of strings using literals.

```
char const *special_character[] = { "\u2780", "\u2781", "\u2782",
  "\u2783", "\u2784", "\u2785", "\u2786", "\u2787", "\u2788", "\u2789" };

std::cout << special_character[i] << '\n';
```

Answer (score 2):

The program prints an integer because of C++11 §2.14.3/1:

> A multicharacter literal, or an ordinary character literal containing a single c-char not representable in the execution character set, is conditionally-supported, has type int, and has an implementation-defined value.

The execution character set is what `char` can represent, i.e., ASCII.

You got 14851712, or in hexadecimal E29E80, which is the UTF-8 representation of [U+2780](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=10104&number=128) (DINGBAT CIRCLED SANS-SERIF DIGIT ONE). Putting UTF-8, a multibyte encoding, into an `int` is insane and stupid, but that's what you get from a "conditionally supported, implementation-defined" feature.

To get a [UTF-32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-32) value, use `U'\u2780'`. The first `U` specifies the `char32_t` type and UTF-32 encoding (i.e. up to 31 bits but no surrogate pairs).  The second `\u` specifies a universal-character-name containing the code point. To get a value supposedly compatible with `wcout`, use `L'\u2780'`, but that doesn't necessarily use a Unicode runtime value nor get you more than two bytes of storage.

As for reliably manipulating and printing the Unicode code point, as other answers have noted, the C++ standard hasn't quite gotten there yet. [Joni's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16944750/c-unicode-characters-printing/16944903#16944903) is the best way, yet it still assumes that the compiler and the user's environment are using the same locale, which often isn't true.

You can also specify UTF-8 strings in the source using `u8"\u2780"` and force the runtime environment to UTF-8 using something like `std::locale::global( std::locale( "en_US.UTF-8" ) );`. But that still has rough edges. Joni suggests using the C interface `std::setlocale` from `<clocale>` instead of the C++ interface `std::locale::global` from `<locale>`, which is a workaround to the C++ interface being broken in GCC on OS X and perhaps other platforms. The issues are platform-sensitive enough that your Linux distribution might well have put a patch into their own GCC package.

Comment: Either you or I probably missed something, because compiler now urges "U was not declared in the scope".

Comment: @Sventimir Apparently it's not supported in GCC 4.7.2, but it's part of the C++11 standard. Just go with `L'xxx'`; in Linux it should do essentially the same thing.

Comment: Adding C++11 support with `gcc --std=c++11` call does not work either. It now compiles, but prints decimal value of the char (10112), not the char itself.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, I have been successful printing out any Unicode directly as in *the* most naive way:

```
std::cout << "ΐ, Α, Β, Γ, Δ, Θ, Λ, Ξ, ... ±, ... etc."
```

Comment: How does that answer the question? It doesn't even include [U+2780](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=10104&number=128).

Comment: [A similar unexplained answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015571/how-to-print-unicode-character-in-c/41546489#41546489).