# Why (const char*) ptr is not regarded as a lvalue

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I have the following [code](https://ideone.com/7jhCTr) (only key code) and [minimal example code](https://ideone.com/Fm6EZ1), but it is illegal because of the line `OFFSET_PTR(pFileBothDirInfo->NextEntryOffset, pFileBothDirInfo);` (IDE error: expression must be a modifiable value. Compile: error C2106: '=': left operand must be l-value.)

```cpp
char packet_bytes[9] = {0};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    printf("(int)sizeof(smb2_query_directory_response_t) = %d\n", (int)sizeof(smb2_query_directory_response_t));
    printf("(int)sizeof(smb2_FileBothDirectoryInformation_t) = %d\n", (int)sizeof(smb2_FileBothDirectoryInformation_t));

    const smb2_query_directory_response_t*  pSMB2QueryDirectoryResponse = (smb2_query_directory_response_t*)packet_bytes;
    const smb2_FileBothDirectoryInformation_t *pFileBothDirInfo = pSMB2QueryDirectoryResponse->OutputBufferLength ? REINTERPRET_CAST(const smb2_FileBothDirectoryInformation_t*, pSMB2QueryDirectoryResponse->Buffer) : NULL;
    while (pFileBothDirInfo)
    {
        // ideone runs on linux with a compiler who consider wchar_t 4 bytes?
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16944750/c-unicode-characters-printing
        //wprintf(L"%.*s|%.*s\n", pFileBothDirInfo->FileNameLength/2, pFileBothDirInfo->FileName, pFileBothDirInfo->ShortNameLength/2, pFileBothDirInfo->ShortName);
        if (pFileBothDirInfo->NextEntryOffset)
        {
            offset_ptr(pFileBothDirInfo->NextEntryOffset, pFileBothDirInfo);

            const unsigned char *ptrTemp;
            ptrTemp = ((const unsigned char*)pFileBothDirInfo + 10);
            //be equivalent to 
            //((const unsigned char*)pFileBothDirInfo) = ( (const unsigned char*)pFileBothDirInfo + 10 );
            OFFSET_PTR(pFileBothDirInfo->NextEntryOffset, pFileBothDirInfo);
            *((int *)10) = 100;
            printf("ptrTemp = %p", ptrTemp);
        } 
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I also referred to [L-Value and R-Value Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/l-value-and-r-value-expressions?view=vs-2019)

> An **lvalue** has an address that your program can access. Examples of lvalue expressions include variable names, including `const` variables, array elements, function calls that return an lvalue reference, bit-fields, unions, and class members.

and [L-Value and R-Value Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/l-value-and-r-value-expressions?view=vs-2019), which points out that the following code is legal, but The VS2015 IDE and its compiler gave me an error.

```c
char *p;
short i;
long l;

(long *)p = &l;     /* Legal cast   */
(long)i = l;        /* Illegal cast */
```

It has a similar error using [ideone](https://ideone.com/Fm6EZ1) compiler:

```
Compilation error   #stdin compilation error #stdout 0s 15232KB
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
prog.cpp:259:33: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
    OFFSET_PTR(pFileBothDirInfo->NextEntryOffset, pFileBothDirInfo);
                                 ^
prog.cpp:235:107: note: in definition of macro ‘OFFSET_PTR’
 #define OFFSET_PTR(byte_offset, ref_ptr) ((const unsigned char*)ref_ptr = (const unsigned char*)ref_ptr + byte_offset)
```

I think `(const unsigned char*)pFileBothDirInfo` has an address, but why it isn't considered as a lvalue?

References

- [Quick Q: What are rvalues, lvalues, xvalues, glvalues, and prvalues?](https://isocpp.org/blog/2016/04/quick-q-what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues)
- [C++ International Standard (Working Draft, Standard for Programming Language C++ n4618.pdf)](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/n4618.pdf)
- [Value categories](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category)
- [Bjarne Stroustrup's explanation: “New” Value Terminology](http://www.stroustrup.com/terminology.pdf)
- [L-Value and R-Value Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/l-value-and-r-value-expressions?view=vs-2019)
- [Lvalues and Rvalues (C++)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/lvalues-and-rvalues-visual-cpp?view=vs-2019)
- [What are rvalues, lvalues, xvalues, glvalues, and prvalues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues)
- [L value vs R value in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26129586/l-value-vs-r-value-in-c)
- [What is lvalue and rvalue in C?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-lvalue-and-rvalue-in-C)
- [lvalue and rvalue in C language](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lvalue-and-rvalue-in-c-language/)
- [Lvalues and rvalues](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_73/rzarg/lvalue.htm)
- [3.10 Lvalues and rvalues [basic.lval]](http://www.lcdf.org/c%2B%2B/clause3.html#s3.10)
- [3.10 Lvalues and rvalues](http://timepp.github.io/doc/cpp14/basic.lval.html)

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but there's a specific `printf` format specifier for the type `size_t` (which is returned by `sizeof`): `"%zu"`. Or just use `std::cout` and the overloaded `<<` operator.

Comment: I also can't help but think that your [mcve] could be even more minimal, without losing any important information.

Comment: `*((int *)10) = 100;` What the hell is this?

Comment: That last piece of code relies on an MS "extension" that makes some "cast-assignments" legal. Neither assignment is valid in standard C or C++.

Comment: Quoting from the section 3.10 you linked to (item 6): "An expression which holds a temporary object resulting from a cast to a nonreference type is an rvalue".

Comment: That `OFFSET_PTR` macro is strange and very strange. You could go with some `template<T> void OFFSET_PTR(size_t n, T*& ptr) { ptr = reinterpret_cast<T*>(reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(ptr) + n); }`.

Comment: `*((int *)10) = 100` has been removed, it's just a test.

Comment: It's a little hard for me to understand: An expression which holds a temporary object resulting from a cast to a nonreference type is an rvalue. It means `(const unsigned char*)pFileBothDirInfo` is a  temporary object?

Comment: You can keep it lispy with ref_ptr = (decltype(ref_ptr))((char*)ref_ptr + (byte_offset))

Comment: In fact, based on "The default for Microsoft C is that the Microsoft extensions are enabled. Use the /Za compiler option to disable these extensions.", I didn't use the option, but it still output two lines of error: "error C2106: '=': left operand must be l-value"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think `(const unsigned char*)pFileBothDirInfo` has an address, but why it isn't considered as a lvalue?

You think wrong.

> The result of the expression (T) *cast-expression* is of type T. The result is an lvalue if T is [an lvalue reference type or an rvalue reference to function type] and an xvalue if T is [an rvalue reference to object type]; otherwise the result is a prvalue.

[`[expr.cast]`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.cast#1) ([] brackets added to group clauses)

`const unsigned char*` is not any kind of reference type, so the result is a prvalue.

You are creating a value of type `const unsigned char*`. Why would it be associated with the storage of an object of type `const smb2_FileBothDirectoryInformation_t *`?

MSVC allows `(long *)p = &l;` as an extension.

Comment: prvalue? Did you mean rvalue?

Comment: @Broman no, I'm applying the quote from the standard. prvalue is a sub-category of rvalue.

Comment: The term prvalue does not exist anywhere in the standard.

Comment: @Broman [Yes it does](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.lval), since C++11

Comment: My mistake. I came here from a C question that was marked as a duplicate of this one.

Answer (score 1):

`OFFSET_PTR` is broken.

Yes, `pFileBothDirInfo` has an address, but `(const unsigned char*)pFileBothDirInfo` is a temporary. An rvalue. That's what happens when you perform a cast to a value type! You get a *fresh* object of the new type.

The other problem is that it is `const`. You can't modify `const` things. That's what it means.

Comment: `pFileBothDirInfo` is a mutable pointer to `const smb2_FileBothDirectoryInformation_t`, so incrementing the pointer is ok.

Comment: @Caleth There's literally a cast to a `const` type in the expression. How do you suggest to mutate that?