# How to convert a hex code value to a unicode char

Tags: c++, unicode, hex

Can someone tell me how to display a corresponding unicode character for a given input hex value

For example, consider I have a buffer which contain data like this 
[00210028004d015500abffff....]. Now i need to take set of four bytes and then convert that to equivalent unicode character.

So the output of this buffer will be !(M... (Don't know what are the unicode equivalent of 0155,00ab,ffff)

I can use a code like this to print an ascii char

```
    int t=65;
    char asciiChar = static_cast<char>(t);
    printf("%s",asciiChar);
```

and the output will be 'A'

Similarly is there any method to get Unicode chars

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows use the functions described [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34068/Unicode-Output-to-the-Windows-Console)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
char myChar = '\u0028';
```

Comment: Why not use a `char`?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Because in this context a `char` does not hold a character.

Comment: One for the escape character, one for the octo and one for the null terminator.

Comment: @JosephPla That depends on various factors (but the code is ill-formed anyway, because string literals are not convertible to `char*`).

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes What do you mean?

Comment: Actually, scratch that. It doesn't really depend on anything (I was thinking of the source character set, but left parenthesis is on the basic one). There's no escape character, and there's no octo. That literal is equivalent to `"("` which does not have three `char`s.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Ok thanks for the info but I'm not quite sure what was wrong with my answer.

Comment: When i used that i got an error "error C3851: '\u0028': a universal-character-name cannot designate a character in the basic character set
"

Comment: And its not 0028 always. I need to convert the values in a buffer to its unicode char

Comment: @Vinod Paul, check this question out. You'll find it useful I think. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015571/how-to-print-unicode-character-in-c

Comment: @VinodPaul change your IDE settings to a unicode character set.

Comment: @VinodPaul sounds like the example you gave was misleading then. I recommend providing a more accurate example. Giving an example of Y when you want to do X doesn't really help.