# Print the complete Unicode charset in c++ iterativly

Tags: c++, unicode

Simple Task:
I want to find out how the Windows explorer is sorting

for that purpose I want to create folders with a single unicode chars as name,
but i dont get how you print all unicode characters ...

via '\u0xxx' 
my compiler says i can't use them for the base charset.

im pretty sure there has to be a simple answer but im not gettin it.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to print unicode character in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015571/how-to-print-unicode-character-in-c)

Comment: Do you really want to print *all* Unicode characters? There are currently over 100,000 code points assigned to characters (some of which are by definition non-printable).

Comment: well at least the printable ones i thought it would be easier to just skip them with an error then gettin the needed ranges by hand

Comment: Regarding explorer, what if it's using the "sorting intuitively" feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(WCHAR i = 0; i < WCHAR_MAX; ++i)
    create_directory_somehow(i);
```

(You may need to #include "wchar.h")

But I also think it's not a good idea - the file system may not like it...

Answer (score 0):

Okay I solved it with the help of Macieks comment :D

```
for(WCHAR i = 0; i < WCHAR_MAX; ++i)
{
    LPCWSTR lpcChar = &wcChar;
    CreateDirectoryW(lpcChar,NULL);
}
```

Thanks a lot i knew it has to be some easy way to do this

Comment: This won't print out all Unicode characters. It will only print the first 65,536 characters (some of which aren't actually valid Unicode characters), while Unicode v6.3 supports 110,187 different characters.

Comment: You need to null-terminate the string you pass to `CreateDirectoryW()`. You can use a `WCHAR[2]` array for that.

Comment: Windows is based on UTF-16, and `wchar_t` is 16-bit on Windows. Your example only covers codepoints in the BMP.  It does not cover codepoints that use surrogate pairs in UTF-16. Windows supports surrogates, even in file/folder names. If you really want to loop through ALL codepoints then loop using an `int` from 0 to 0x10FFFF, converting each value to a UTF-16 sequence as needed, and then using that sequence as the folder name.