# Airplane symbol using Unicode C++

Tags: c++, unicode, iostream

I'm trying to print the Airplane symbol using Unicode in my CodeBlocks. I found out that the code of Airplane is `\u2708`. So I tried the following code:

```
   #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    wchar_t a = '\u2708';
    cout << a;
return 0;
}
```

It outputs `40072` when I replace wchar_t with char

```
char a = '\u2708';
```

I get this symbol: `ł`

Im really stuck, thanks for any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to print unicode character in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015571/how-to-print-unicode-character-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in `Linux` and dont use codepage conversion from unicode to console try this:

```
std::locale::global(std::locale(""));
wchar_t plane = L'\u2708';
std::wcout << plane << std::endl;
```

In windows is a bit more complicated, you need a compatible unicode font on the default console and the correct codepage.