# How can I display Greek characters in Visual Studio 2008 and C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

How can I display Greek characters and strings, using plain C++ and VS 2008 Express?

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << 'Φ' << std::endl;
    std::cout << 'Ξ' << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Καλημέρα" << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

by the way i am getting warnings like below

```
1>d:\02_visualstudio2008projects\displaygreek\displaygreek\displaygreek.cpp(5) : warning C4566: character represented by universal-character-name '\u03A6' cannot be represented in the current code page (1252)
```

Comment: I believe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015571/how-to-print-unicode-character-in-c) answers your question.

Comment: ok, but what is the apropriate code page?

Comment: http://unicode-table.com/en/

Comment: I'll add this as an answer so you can (maybe) accept it.

Comment: @phantom simply flag as duplicate then please.

Comment: i am sorry, but i dont get it. I was thinking that i could use the greek keybord to input characters and strings and not to input something like U+03A6 instead of 'Φ'.

Comment: @DimZon You can if you have the correct encoding on your source file.

Comment: ok, i have try the following 5 encodings without success. Greek(DOS) 737, Greek (ISO) 28597, Greek(Mac)10006, Greek(Windows) 10006 and Greek(Moden) 869. So, what will be the appropriate encoding?

Comment: @DimZon Check my updated answer for this^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways you can approach this.

### Method #1: Embedded unicode

This is useful for those who have a keyboard that allows direct input of unicode characters.  You can define a variable like this:

```
char a = 'ф';
```

All this requires is that the encoding of your source file is set to UTF-8.

### Method #2: Universal Character Names (UCNs)

With this method, you use coded form `\u#` where the `#` is the UCN.

```
char a = '\u0444';
```

A good place to find the UCN values is [here](http://unicode-table.com/en/).

<sub>Some code samples taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015571/how-to-print-unicode-character-in-c).</sub>

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Seitaridis My apologies.  I'm paranoid about plagiarism.  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: And i guess, strings will be treated as char arrays, is that so? By the way, there are 3 UTF-8 codepages available, all of them produce the same uglly outputs as before with Greek codepages.

Comment: @DimZon It's possible that could be due to your console's font not supporting unicode...not necessarily a coding error.

Comment: How can i check this out?

Comment: @DimZon I'm not sure...it's not really within the scope of this question or SO.

Comment: @DimZon Your original question was answered already.

Comment: Thank you for your "clean" answer. I will accept it and try some more investigation about the console