# How to print qubic meter in C++ with unicode?

Tags: c++, windows, unicode

Lead by this page([How to print Unicode character in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015571/how-to-print-unicode-character-in-c)), I can print Russian "ф".but when try to print "m³"(\u 33a5), I got a "?".

[image]

Please anyone can help me.

Answer (score 1):

Console normally does not support displaying unicode characters. Try solution for this question [Unicode characters in Windows command line - how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how)

Comment: Yes, as Windows normally doesn't support Unicode :)

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov: Windows itself supports Unicode – it uses [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=UTF-16&oldid=717435654) extensively in many of its APIs. cmd, however, defaults to a legacy code page (the precise page is determined by your locale) and requires an explicit switch into Unicode mode.

Comment: so does it means that if m^3 is output into a file but not console,  everything will be right?

Comment: @BenjaminBarenblat the command window also supports full UTF-16, if you use the console API to interact with it (and the selected font contains the characters you need). It's only the character-based interface that suffers. Unfortunately the whole point of having a command window is to use the character-based interface.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>

int main()
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    std::wcout << L"m\u00B3" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```