# How to print Greek letter delta in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, unicode, console, non-ascii-characters

I have a small console based application that will solve physics equations. I am trying to ask the user if they want to find the ΔV in a given situation, but I can't figure out how to print the letter delta to the console. Here's my code:

```
cout << "Select what you would like to find:\n"
<< "1 - Acceleration" << endl
<< "2 - Initial Velocity" << endl
<< "3 - Final Velocity" << endl
<< "4 -  ΔV" << "\n\n";
cin >> choice;
```

This does not print "ΔV" to the console. The "Δ" doesn't even display in my IDE (Dev-C++), instead being displayed as a question mark. If anyone knows how I can print Δ to the console I would highly appreciate any help you can give me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to the awful world of text encoding. Good luck getting an answer but I expect this might be surprisingly awkward based on your system config and compiler.

Comment: Half the duplicate: [How to print Unicode character in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015571/how-to-print-unicode-character-in-c)

Comment: oh boy howdy are you in for a ride

Comment: Oh come on, folks. It's much easier than it used to be. We no longer have so sacrifice our first-born.

Comment: @user4581301 just our second-born

Comment: *The "Δ" doesn't even display in my IDE (Dev-C++).* Wait, how did you type that in the first place? Does your keyboard have a Delta key you can use? Did you add that character from another editor, outside of your IDE? Can you tell us more about this?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi It's likely that he copied the character from somewhere or simply added the Greek language in his keyboard settings to type it (typically it's the same key as the letter D).

Comment: Does your console font support this character?

Comment: What operating system are you using? If it's Dec-C++ on Windows it gets more complicated.

Comment: It might not be a useful comment, but as far as I know, Windows' console is poorly tolerant to non-ascii characters. I used to want to print Japanese characters in Python, and well, I just could not. Although, Pyzo's console (yet another Python IDE) displayed them perfectly. Long story short, maybe the console you are using just cannot do this.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If your platform supports it, you could use unicode escape characters. For Greek capital delta the code is `\u0394`:

```
#include <iostream>
int
main() {
  std::cout << "\u0394V" << '\n';
}
```

output: `ΔV`

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e611d98575f17b6d)

For the future reader, bellow I give the escape sequences for Greek capital letters:

```
Letter   Description  Escape-Sequence
-------------------------------------
A        Alpha        \u0391
B        Beta         \u0392
Γ        Gamma        \u0393
Δ        Delta        \u0394
Ε        Epsilon      \u0395
Ζ        Zeta         \u0396
Η        Eta          \u0397
Θ        Theta        \u0398
Ι        Iota         \u0399
Κ        Kappa        \u039A
Λ        Lambda       \u039B
Μ        Mu           \u039C
Ν        Nu           \u039D
Ξ        Xi           \u039E
Ο        Omicron      \u039F
Π        Pi           \u03A0
Ρ        Rho          \u03A1
Σ        Sigma        \u03A3
Τ        Tau          \u03A4
Υ        Upsilon      \u03A5
Φ        Phi          \u03A6
Χ        Chi          \u03A7
Ψ        Psi          \u03A8
Ω        Omega        \u03A9
```

and for Greek lower letters:

```
Letter   Description  Escape-Sequence
-------------------------------------
α        Alpha        \u03B1
β        Beta         \u03B2
γ        Gamma        \u03B3
δ        Delta        \u03B4
ε        Epsilon      \u03B5
ζ        Zeta         \u03B6
η        Eta          \u03B7
θ        Theta        \u03B8
ι        Iota         \u03B9
κ        Kappa        \u03BA
λ        Lambda       \u03BB
μ        Mu           \u03BC
ν        Nu           \u03BD
ξ        Xi           \u03BE
ο        Omicron      \u03BF
π        Pi           \u03C0
ρ        Rho          \u03C1
σ        Sigma        \u03C3
τ        Tau          \u03C4
υ        Upsilon      \u03C5
φ        Phi          \u03C6
χ        Chi          \u03C7
ψ        Psi          \u03C8
ω        Omega        \u03C9
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/06846c0276b80ea5)

For people interested on other alphabets, as well as on other symbols, you could find more supported escape characters [**here**](http://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/unicode-characters.htm).

Comment: Unfortunately, @101010 , it appears the command prompt does not support the Greek Unicode escape characters. Instead of printing `Δ`, it prints `╬ö` ([here's a screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/21u3qtu09qofbwj/delta.png?dl=0)). I'll try some different console applications and see if any of those works. Thanks!

Comment: Try what Howard proposed (i.e., "\xCE\x94V") I've tested on windows compiler and it works. Have in mind though that this stuff is not standard.