# Drawing greek symbols in opencv using putText and FreeFontStyle

Tags: c++, opencv, unicode, special-characters, freetype

I've seen the following questions, in Python language, about how to write special characters that aren't supported by the Hershey Font Style used in `putText` function from Opencv: How to [write russian letters in the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015571/how-to-print-unicode-character-in-c) and [How to draw chinese letter in the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50854235/how-to-draw-chinese-text-on-the-image-using-cv2-puttextcorrectly-pythonopen) and [How to write greek letter in console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40272566/how-to-print-greek-letter-delta-in-c).

I would like to draw greek letters using UTF-8 strings with [freetype2](https://docs.opencv.org/4.3.0/d4/dfc/group__freetype.html) class using `putText`. The second link is slighty what I want, but I saw it use a PIL option as well, but I'm not using Python. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As @berak mentioned in [this answer](https://answers.opencv.org/question/86997/how-can-i-put-text-on-image-using-opencv-puttext-function/), this is not possible by using `putText()`. It only supports ascii subset.

But you can achieve it by using [addText()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dc/d46/group__highgui__qt.html#ga4e2751b94f709c848f0658d78007e449) if you installed opencv with `-D WITH_QT = ON`

Here is the simple code with Greek letters and result:

[image]

```
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat img = Mat::zeros(Size(1000,1000),CV_8UC3);


    namedWindow("Window",0);
    cv::addText(img, "Greek Letters: ", cv::Point(50, 100), "Times",30,Scalar(0,255,255),QT_FONT_NORMAL,QT_STYLE_NORMAL);
    cv::addText(img, "alpha: α", cv::Point(50, 200), "Times",30,Scalar(0,255,255),QT_FONT_NORMAL,QT_STYLE_NORMAL);
    cv::addText(img, "betta: β", cv::Point(50, 300), "Times",30,Scalar(0,255,255),QT_FONT_NORMAL,QT_STYLE_NORMAL);
    cv::addText(img, "gamma: γ", cv::Point(50, 400), "Times",30,Scalar(0,255,255),QT_FONT_NORMAL,QT_STYLE_NORMAL);
    cv::addText(img, "delta: δ", cv::Point(50, 500), "Times",30,Scalar(0,255,255),QT_FONT_NORMAL,QT_STYLE_NORMAL);
    cv::addText(img, "epsilon: ε", cv::Point(50, 600), "Times",30,Scalar(0,255,255),QT_FONT_BOLD,QT_STYLE_NORMAL);


    imshow("Window",img);

    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good to know! I'll check how to re-build my opencv with 'WITH_QT' enabled. I saw at the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/master/db/d05/tutorial_config_reference.html) that it is set off by default. How could I've lived without Qt functionalities all this time!? If i fail, I'll simply add the equation I want as image.