# Print unicode char

Tags: c++, linux, unicode, char, c++14

I tried a very simple code in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::wstring test = L"asdfa-";
  test += u'ç';
  std::wcout << test;
}
```

But the result was:

```
asdfa-?
```

It was not possible print 'ç', with cout or wcout, how can I can print this string correctally?

OS: Linux.

Ps: I use `wstring` instead of `string`, because sometimes I need calculate the length of the string, and this size must be the same of what is on the screen.

Ps: I need concatenate the unicode char, it can't be on the string constructor.

Comment: What is the target platform?

Comment: Linux, I edited the post. Thanks Phil Brubaker.

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12015571/6610379

Comment: I saw this post, it didn't help me.

Comment: What's the encoding of your source file? What does your compiler *assume* it is? What happens if you replace `u'ç'` with `u'\xe7'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem using a conversion function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <codecvt>
#include <locale>

std::string wstr2str(const std::wstring& wstr) {
  std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> myconv;
  return myconv.to_bytes(wstr);
}

int main()
{
  std::wstring test = L"asdfa-";
  test += L'ç';
  std::string str = wstr2str(test)
  std::cout << str;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

First, here's something that *does* work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string test = "asdfa-";
    test += "ç";
    std::cout << test;
}
```

I used just regular strings here and let C++ keep everything in UTF-8. I think you already know that this would work because you mentioned that you wanted to concatenate the ç rather than just leaving it in the string constructor.

Dealing with `char`, `char16_t`, `char32_t`, and `wchar_t` in C++ has never really been fun. You have to be careful with the `L`, `u`, and `U` prefixes.

However, where possible, if you deal with utf-8 strings, and avoid characters, you can generally get things to work much better. And since most consoles (with the possible exception of old Windows machines) understand utf-8 pretty well, this is the approach that often just works the best. So if you have wide characters, see if you can convert them to regular `std::string` objects and work in that domain.

Comment: The problem for me is that i need to calculate string length, and 'ç' make the length different from what print on the screen.

Comment: Why do you need to calculate the length of the string? That operation is usually a code smell. Most applications do not need it. Anyway, that's messy too..., Do you mean the number of bytes, the number of characters, or the number of graphemes?

Comment: @Alex If you need to calculate the length of what is printed on the screen in character cells, you're out of luck. A Unicode character (== code point, a `wchar_t` in C and C++ on Linux) may take up  0, 1, or more cells, and a cell may contain 1 or more Unicode characters. There is no way to determine any of this using Standard C++.

Answer (score 1):

One general way of handling this would be:

1. Input (convert from multibyte to wide using current locale)
2. Your App: work with wide strings
3. Output or saving to a file (convert from wide to multibyte)

For wide string manipulations like num of characters, substring etc. there is wcsXXX class of functions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `libstdc++` on Linux: you forgot an essential call at the beginning of the program

```
std::locale::global(std::locale(""));
```

This is assuming you are on Linux and your locale supports UTF-8.

If you are using `libc++`: forget about using `wstream`s. This library does not support I/O of wide characters in a useful way (i.e. translation to UTF-8 like `libstdc++` does).

Windows has a wholly separate set of quirks regarding Unicode. You are lucky if you don't have to deal with them.

[demo with gcc/libstdc++ and a call to std::locale](https://ideone.com/4Mn9oH)

[demo with gcc/libstdc++ and no call to std::locale](https://ideone.com/6MrC8Q)

Different versions of clang/libc++ behave differently with this example: some output `?` instead of the non-ascii char, some output nothing; some crash on call to std::locale, some don't. None do the right thing, which is printing the `ç`, or maybe I just haven't found one that works. I don't recommend using libc++ if you need anything related to locale or wchar_t.