# How to print a non ascii-char in c++

Tags: c++, char

I'm learning C++ and I cannot figure out how how to print special characters in C++. Even when I've seen others post related to this issue, any of them solves this:

I just want to print out this chars -> '♦', '♥', '♣', '♠';

And when I do this ->

```
std::cout << '♦' << std::endl;
```

It prints out a number such as 14850470, but when I pass the char to a function, such as ->

```
char foo(char a) 
{
    return a;
}
int main()
{
    std::cout << foo('♦') << std::endl;
}
```

It prints out 'ª' instead, any ideas?

(I'm writing this in VSCode with the MSVC compiler on Windows.)

**EDIT:**
The answers solved my problem (I executed `chcp 65001` on the CL). But I have to change this `std::cout << '♠' << std::endl;` to this `std::cout << "♠" << std::endl;` in order to work, since printing as char prints nothing on the console.

Comment: This question has already been marked as a duplicate, so new answers cannot be added.  However, I thought it useful to explain the reported behavior.

My guess is that the source file is UTF-8 encoded, but that the Microsoft compiler is invoked without either the `/utf-8` or `/source-charset:utf-8` options.  In this case, the compiler will interpret the source file according to the active code page, probably Windows-1252.  The ♦ character is encoded as E2 99 A6 in UTF-8.  If interpreted as Windows-1252, this makes `'♦'` a multi-character literal with type `int`.

Comment: The value of multi-character literals is implementation defined (http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.ccon#2).  The Microsoft compiler implements them via a logical left shift of the current literal value (initially 0) by 8 bits followed by a logical-or of the current code unit.  So, the series of code units E2 99 A6 in `'♦'` (when interpreted as Windows-1252) results in an `int` value of `0x00E299A6` or 14850470.

Comment: So what you have going on here is typical mojibake.  In addition to having to run `chmod 65001` to set the console encoding, you should also compile with (minimally) the `/source-charset:utf-8` option so that the source code is read as UTF-8 by the compiler, and possibly with `/execution-charset:utf-8` so that the compiler doesn't transcode the (utf-8) literals read from the source code to the ACP (the default execution character encoding).  But be careful with the `/execution-charset:utf-8` option as it doesn't affect the actual run-time encoding!

Comment: Great explanation, thank you so much! I've tried running those commands  along with my executable, but the result is the same, only the `"♣"` got printed out, printing `'♣'` prints a number as you said, and `u8"♣"` prints another character, in my case, `â™ `

Comment: If `u8"♣"` prints something different, that is again because mojibake is occurring; either due to a mismatch of encoding expectations for your source file, for the execution encoding, or for the console.  Again, I suspect what is happening is that your source file is UTF-8 encoded, and you are compiling without the `/source-charset:utf-8` or `/utf-8` options.  The contents of the literal will then be interpreted according to the ACP.  Assuming Windows-1252, the UTF-8 bytes E2 99 A3 would produce a string containing `"â™£"`.  I'm not sure why the last character isn't printing "right" for you.

Comment: @Tom Oh, I was running those commands along with the executable, now I have run them along with the compile, and it works! Now I get the expected character printing `"♣"` and `u8"♣"`. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no portable way.

On Linux/mac, the terminal recently adopted UTF-8 as default. So, when you output a UTF-8 binary to the standard output, you can see the '♦' character.

On Windows 10 1607 or later, `chcp 65001` will work fine except when printing color emoji. Since the broken font config dialog is fixed and you can use a TrueType font for `chcp 65001` console. In your program, you should output a  UTF-8 binary to the standard output. Before you run your program, run `chcp 65001` and configure the font.

On windows before Windows 10 1607, you should give up trying to print Unicode.

---

On C++20, the C++ standard committee adopt `char8_t` that's assumed to hold UTF-8. In the future, C++ (C++26? C++29?), when `<locale>` and `<iostream>` is recreated and support `char8_t`, you can printf a Unicode character portably.

---

In my opinion, you should give up trying to print Unicode characters. Create a GUI using some library which supports TrueType fonts and OpenType.

Comment: This actually solves my problem, but I have to change this `std::cout << '♠' << std::endl;` to this `std::cout << "♠" << std::endl;` in order to work, since printing as char prints nothing on the console. I guess I'd have to conform.

Comment: Note: it's better to use u8 string literal prefix(C++11, `u8"♥♠"`) or u8 character literal prefix(C++17, `u8'♠'`). Don't forget setting the font.

Comment: adding those prefixes make the CL not displaying the chars correctly again. `std::cout << u8"♠" << std::endl;` prints out `â™ `

Comment: `chcp 65001` before execute

Comment: Still not working

Comment: https://imgur.com/xNfoMiB

Comment: I don't have the font "Hack Gen"

Comment: https://github.com/yuru7/HackGen/releases

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're happy to have your code only work in Windows I think the answer to your question can be found here:

[How to use unicode characters in Windows command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/how-to-use-unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line)

The answer doesn't go into a lot of detail, this should help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/low-level-console-output-functions

This way might be quicker and easier though: [How to print Unicode character in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015571/how-to-print-unicode-character-in-c)