# C++ Print ASCII symbols (specifically greek symbols) to a notepad file & terminal window

Tags: c++, ascii

I'm trying to print ASCII greek symbols to a notepad file and the terminal window.
From what if seen, this appears to be pretty complex. Is there a simple way to approach this? Possibly a prewritten library I can use? Does Microsoft have anything readily available to use?

Right now, the symbol simply prints as a question mark. My code and system information is provided below.

Compiler: Visual Studio 2019
OS: Windows 10

CODE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    cout << "φ" << endl;
    system("pause");

    ofstream out;
    out.open("test.txt");
    out << "φ" << endl;
    out.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015571/how-to-print-unicode-character-in-c

Comment: You may want to do read this for a bit of background information: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Comment: ASCII is *literally* American. It's not Greek. It has A-Z and a-z, and not one letter more.