# C++ special chars

Tags: c++, windows, char, mingw

I'm just starting to learn C++ and I wanted to know how to display special characters like in this french sentence `"J'aime le café"` and I don't want to have to put something like `\uefdddf`. I want to be able to display the char with this code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    printf("J'aime le café");
}
```

I want it to display this French sentence `J'aime le café` in the terminal, not `J'aime le cafÚ`.

I've searched the web for several answers but haven't found what I'm looking for. I hope you can help me.
I'm using windows 10 and MinGW.

Comment: Unfortunately, printing/reading non-ASCII heavily depends on your operating system, compiler, the exact way you compile and run the program. Sometimes OS settings as well (e.g. "locale").

Comment: Have you heard of the C++ I/O streams?  Like [`std::cout` and `std::wcout`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout)?

Comment: If you have a strong objection to C++ I/O streams, you should review the C language [*wide* I/O streams](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwprintf).

Comment: You can use `u8` ([UTF-8 string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal)).

Comment: Proper internationalization and locale-related topics and issues are a surprisingly advanced topic in C++, and suffers from rather poor, and cumbersome support. Thankfully, there's plenty to learn about C++ for someone who's just starting to learn it, and there won't be any shortage of core C++ fundamental topics to be covered, before delving into these tangled subjects...

Comment: @JesperJuhl The trick is "what to do next" though. As Sam points out, there's plenty of info out there, but it's certainly not an easy subject.

Comment: [Some wisdom on the wonderful world you're starting to explore](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/).

Comment: @SamVarshavchik This comment doesn't answer my question

Comment: It does, it's just a tactful way of pointing out that before tackling thorny issues of internationalization and localization, someone who's learning C++ will learn the following, first: classes, templates, pointers, references, inheritance, multiple inheritance, polymorphism, overloading, templates, variadic templates, type traits, metaprogramming, concepts, and many more core C++ fundamentals, before getting into boutique specialized domains, like internationalization.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print Unicode character in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015571/how-to-print-unicode-character-in-c)